# Error in Function to Determine number of digits in a number

Tags: javascript, html

I have a simple javascript function that tells me how many digits are in a number.

**My Problem:** On the last line I get a compiler error saying "Missing last ')' parenthisis". I am altering a snippet I found through google & it uses the function Math.log10() but I am not sure a function like this exists?

Can you help me to determine the number of digits in a number (eg 1000 = 4, 10 = 2, etc.)?

```
function getDigitCount( number )
{
    //return ((number ==0) ? 1 : (int)Math.log10(number) + 1);

    if ( (number == 0) )
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else return ((int)Math.log10(number) + 1);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You cannot cast to an `int` in Javascript. Instead, use `Math.floor`. Also, divide by `Math.log(10)` (or `Math.LN10`) instead of using `Math.log10()` to find the base 10 logarithm of a number.:

```
else return (Math.floor(Math.log(number)/Math.log(10)) + 1);
```

Comment: Note that due the floating point arithmetic on Javascript, this solution may not work in some cases, e.g.: `(Math.floor(Math.log(1000)/Math.log(10)) + 1) == 3`

Answer (score 1):

You may try this:
Assuming that "number" is a positive integer value

```
function getDigitCount(number)
{
   var c = "x" + number;
   return c.length -1;
}
```

Comment: `return ("" + number).length`, if the standard toString implementation is "okay"

Comment: "x" is an "warranty" to misinterpretation :).. I've already seen that number + "" stay a number internally ...

Comment: Nope. If either side of the `+` is a string the result is a string; it is converted via the `toString` ("implementation") method.

Comment: var c; c= 10; c="+" + c ; c;  give the string "+10" but eval(c) gives the number 10... by concatenating a non numeric string character liek "ù" for instance, you avoid any ambiguity. the String stay string in all context.(May be not efficient but from my experience it requires less debuging ;) This issue occurs quite often when you manipulate phone number with international code (+1 820 . and you want to keep the "+" sign in any context)